# Load file in matlab ralative to script location

Tags: matlab

I have a simple script in matlab and I want to load a file. It seems it only works if the file is in the same dir as the script. If I add the file to a directory it does not read it.

For example:

```
fileID = fopen('myfile','r' ,'n', 'US-ASCII');
```

but when I put `myfile` in `files`:

```
fileID = fopen('files/myfile','r' ,'n', 'US-ASCII');
```

or

```
fileID = fopen('./files/myfile','r' ,'n', 'US-ASCII');
```

I get a -1 as a fileID. File cannot be read.

Comment: It looks like you misspelled `myfile` as `myfiles`. It probably can't find your file because there is no such name. Also, for OS independence, use `fullfile` to provide OS independent directory separators: `fileID = fopen(fullfile('files', 'myfile'), 'r', 'n', 'US-ASCII');`.

Comment: It works in my case o.O. I have the script in folder `\script` and `myfile` in folder `\script\myfiles`. I have these two lines in the script `addpath('files'); 
fileID = fopen('myfile','r' ,'n', 'US-ASCII')`

Comment: @rayryeng, fixed my question, tried what you said, still returning. -1. the folder 'files' is in the same dir as the script.

Comment: What happens when you type in `A = dir('files'); names = {A.name}; celldisp(names);`? Do you see `myfile` in the result?  If not, then either the file doesn't exist or you are not providing the right directory where the file is.

Comment: @rayryeng no i dont see anything, I don frikking get it, the folder is there right next to the script

Comment: When you type in `ls` in the Command Prompt and push ENTER, do you see the script and the directory?  It would also help if you provided a screen shot of your current command prompt, with the directory listing included.

Comment: @rayryeng omg.... it is still pointing to my old PATH... /Users/username/Documents/MATLAB, and I am in a completely different folder... how can I force matlab to use the current folder the script is in ?

Comment: oops :D.  At the top of the GUI, you can change the path to where your script and folder are located.  You will see the directory listing at the top. 
 Click anywhere you see a blank space so that it terms into a text box.  Type in the path there.  You can do that, or use the `cd` function.  Also, if you run the script inside the MATLAB Editor, it will actually prompt you saying that the path is not currently set to where the script is placed and it'll ask you if you want to change directories.

Comment: Ahh so I guess you pressed "add path" rather than "change path" when you first run your script, so the current path will be "Matlab" path. In almost all cases, you should choose "change path".

Comment: @rayryeng and I just said the same thing lol

Comment: @Anthony I suspected he did Add Path and it didn't add the subdirectory where the file was located.  Problem solved.

Comment: @TrtTrt No problem.  Added an answer for completeness.  Good luck!  I've also added in an animated GIF to sweeten the pot.

Comment: Hi @TrtTrt can I kindly remind you that you haven't accepted a solution here unless you are still looking for an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, this is happening because you most likely added the path of where the script was located to your MATLAB path but you did not add the subdirectory where the file was in to your path.  This is why it can't find the file.  Therefore to avoid this in the future, you need to physically change the directory (i.e. the Working Directory) of where MATLAB is currently operating to where your script is stored.

It is then where local referencing should work.  You can do this by either using the [`cd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) function, going to the top of your MATLAB window where you see the directory listing, clicking on the arrow to the right and pulling a drop down menu to change the directory, typing the actual directory you want by clicking on any blank space in the directory listing to enable a text box:

[image]

... or if you are running the code in the MATLAB editor, it'll request that you change directories as the script you are trying to run is not currently located in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can also programmatically add the subfolders in your script directory using [`mfilename`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html), [`fileparts`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html), [`genpath`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genpath.html) and [`addpath`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html):

```
[dir, ~, ~] = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')); % locate your script directory
addpath(genpath(fullfile(dir))); % add the folder and all subfolders to Matlab search directory

% then load your file.
fileID = fopen('myfile','r' ,'n', 'US-ASCII')
```

If it is also important that all outputs should be placed within the same directory as your script file, you can `cd` to your script directory:

```
cd(dir)
```